# Django Exchange

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

i'm trying to develop an exchange application for a project using djongo.
When I try to add a new Order this is what django returns:
[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIShi.png)

The code I wrote is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from djongo.models.fields import ObjectIdField


class Profile(models.Model):
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Order(models.Model):
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

Sorry for the question but I can't understand why it shows me that error, when I try to add a new Profile everything works, but when I try to add a new Order it doesn't work.

Comment: Using fields starting with underscores can lead to troubles in ForeignKeys. And BTW don't name it `id` that's the the default primary key.

Comment: it still doesn't work, even changing the field name.

Answer (score 0):

Make Id field primary,

Try this

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    _id = ObjectIdField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Order(models.Model):
    _id = ObjectIdField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

Comment: same problem, nothing changes